# CONVERT function does not have a proper format for the datetime I need in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, datetime

Could you please help me format date as it is on the screenshot below:

[image]

The closest to it is 109 in the CONVERT function that I'm using, but it doesn't have slashes and space between seconds and PM + I don't need milliseconds there:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: If the built-in formats don't suffice you, there is no way but to concatenate strings from the date parts.

Comment: Can I have an example of how to do it for the format I've sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is super simple. You can use datename(), convert() ... to build your own (though I would do this in frontend):

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = GETUTCDATE();

SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,@d),3) + '/' +
       CAST(DAY(@d) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' +
       CAST(YEAR(@d) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' ' +
       LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@d,22),11)) + ' (UTC)';
```